# Customer's can't purchase our apple subscription because they use a federated Apple ID

Tags: ios, app-store, google-workspace, federated-identity

We are new to this federated Apple ID. We have a Apple subscription application in App store and we have problem with users who use federated Apple IDs. Other normal users use our application without problem. We did more research and understood that this federated Apple ID's used under an organization where they will share the application within themselves (Under a network). We had a hard time to find a solution for this.
What is the workaround to make a federated Apple ID account to do a successful purchase? We are searching for a solution almost a week now. Advance Thanks.

Additional information:- The subscription we are talking about is yearly subscription.

We tried exploring federated Apple IDs and understood that it's used under a organization and they can share the application themselves. So we are not sure what is this affecting a successful purchase?

Answer (score 2):

When an organisation uses federation with Apple Business Manager then the resulting Apple IDs are *managed* Apple IDs. They are [unable to make purchases](https://support.apple.com/en-au/guide/apple-business-manager/axm78b477c81/1/web/1).

A user with a managed Apple ID can log in to the App Store in their device with a personal Apple ID. This is the id that will be billed for in app purchases.

If it is appropriate for the business organisation to pay for the subscription then you may want to consider creating a custom version that does not use IAP. The organisation can distribute this custom version via Apple Business Manager and their MDM and pay you directly.